# If condition is true filter the value and put "yes" next to it else"no"

Tags: excel, vba

Hello i m very new at VBA as i m suffering with an issue here,in filtered cell if the condition is correct then put "yes" else put "NO"

but when i run the code in for LOOP it put the yes data in all even if the condition is not true

```
VBA

Sub check()
   Dim j As Long
   Dim dsheet As Worksheet
   Dim lastrow As Long
   Dim fr As Range
   Dim psheet As Worksheet
   Dim c As Range
  Set dsheet = Worksheets("Workings")
   Set psheet = Worksheets("sheet1")

   lastrow = dsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

   For j = 1 To lastrow
   psheet.Range("M2").Value = dsheet.Range("A2" & j)
    psheet.Range("N2").Value = dsheet.Range("B2" & j)
      psheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=psheet.Range("M2")
psheet.Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=psheet.Range("N2")
  psheet.Range("A2:I" & psheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)

 dsheet.Range("M2").Value = dsheet.Range("A" & j)
    dsheet.Range("N2").Value = dsheet.Range("B" & j)

dsheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=dsheet.Range("M2")
dsheet.Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=dsheet.Range("N2")
 Set fr = psheet.Range("C2:C50").Find(what:="12345", MatchCase:=True)
 For Each c In dsheet.Range("E2:E2000" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

         If fr Is Nothing Then
      dsheet.Range("A2" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
        If c.Offset(, -1).Value = vbNullString Then Exit For
        c.Value = "NO"
       Else

     dsheet.Range("A2" & Range("A" Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells   (xlCellTypeVisible)
        If c.Offset(, -1). Value =vbNullString Then Exit For
        c.Value = "Yes"

   End If
   Next c

Next j

dsheet. AutoFilterMode = False  
psheet. AutoFilterMode = False
   End Sub
```

so, i want the the code to put the "yes" or "NO" according to the condition,It will be great help if anyone help me in this issue

Comment: Please tag the language.

Comment: I guess i did its a vba code for ms excel

Comment: The "tag" is what you have as "filter". I added the language tag. In the future, please add it so experts in the field can find your question easier. It increases the chances your question will be seen by someone that knows the answer.

Comment: Oh thank you i ll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

You need an End If for each If statement. It should be like this: Also, proper indenting helps make your code more readable.

```
   If fr Is Nothing Then
     dsheet.Range("A2" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
     If c.Offset(, -1).Value = vbNullString Then Exit For
     End If
     c.Value = "NO"
   Else 
     dsheet.Range("A2" & Range("A" Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells   
     (xlCellTypeVisible)
        If c.Offset(, -1). Value =vbNullString Then Exit For
        End If
     c.Value = "Yes"
   End If
```

Comment: Thanks but i m getting compile error :else without if